# SQL % Character

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a `t_package` table with `PackageFlags` entry.
I would like to retrieve packages which contains the sub string `"VCCFG=Use_Case_View;"` in the `PackageFlags`.

When I execute the following statement I get the expected result :

```
SELECT * FROM t_package  
WHERE t_package.PackageFlags LIKE 'Recurse=0;'+'VCCFG=Use_Case_View;'
```

But when I execute the same statement with `%`instead of the whole string in PackageFlags, I have no results at all.

```
SELECT * FROM t_package   
WHERE t_package.PackageFlags LIKE '%VCCFG=Use_Case_View;'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Which DBMS you use? Maybe you must add a % at the end to, bacause of trailling blanks.

Comment: @Jens, Thanks, I've tried and nothing changed. Any other ideas?

Comment: Which Database System (Oracle, SQLServer etc) are you using?

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue on http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: @user3165438 Can you please show an output of the first query?

Comment: @radimpe, Thanks, Since I execute the statement from an external software actually I do not know. Is there difference in the meaning of `%` character  between Access, SQL, Oracle?

Comment: @user3165438 yes, there's differences between the LIKE in MySQL and etc. Probably you should try using some keywords available for different DBMS to 'bruteforce' to check which DBMS you're on.

Comment: @Jens, The entries are: Package_ID,Name,PackageFlags. The output is:
94,ProcessView,Recurse=0;VCCFG=Use_Case_View;

Comment: @Sky, Thanks, It supposed to  be one of the following : Access, SQL or Oracle .

Comment: @user3165438 `select @@version` -- MS SQL `select * from v$version` -- Oracle DBMS `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%"` -- MySQL try executing the 3 different commands and see which works.

Comment: @Sky, Since I get correct result when I execute `select * from ...` I assume it is SQL. Thanks.

Comment: @user3165438 use the exact command I provided and check if there's result, all DBMS SQL syntax works with `select * from ...`

Comment: @Sky, I get syntax error. Why should we mind about this? Is there difference with the `%` character?

Comment: @user3165438 okay, it could be Access then, try `LIKE '*VCCFG=Use_Case_View;'` We should mind the DBMS you use, because different DBMS has differences in how it works although the difference might be small. E.g. for [Access](http://office.microsoft.com/en-sg/access-help/like-operator-HP001032253.aspx) the syntax for LIKE wildcard is * instead of %

Comment: @Sky, Yes it is! Please post is as an answer so that I could accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @user3165438 "*I assume it is SQL*" doesn't tell us anything. SQL is just a *query language* it is not the name of a specific DBMS product. All relational DBMS use SQL (Postgres, Oracle, DB2, MySQL, Firebird, Microsoft SQL Server, ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM t_package   
WHERE t_package.PackageFlags LIKE '*VCCFG=Use_Case_View;'
```

After finding out the DBMS you're on; the syntax for [Access](http://office.microsoft.com/en-sg/access-help/like-operator-HP001032253.aspx) wildcard is * instead of %.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use '% %'?

```
SELECT * FROM t_package   
WHERE t_package.PackageFlags LIKE '%SEARCH%'
```